# How to save the template with dynamic data in django

Tags: python, django

I want to save the template with the dynamic data when ever i request it should render the saved page instead of querying again the database. my app is in views.py below is my sample code. please help.

```
def severity_wise(request):
    sev_chart=[["Severity","No. of Bugs"]]
    sev_list=["1","2","3","4","5","6"]

   for i in sev_list:
             sev=dev_report.objects.filter(Q(severity=i),Q(status='S')|Q(status='N')|Q(status='A')|Q(status='O')|Q(status='W')|Q(status='I')|Q(status='P')|Q(status='H'))
    list=["S"+i,len(sev)]
    sev_chart.append(list)
    sev_table=sev_chart[1:]
return render(request, 'WASS/severity_wise.html',{'sc':sev_chart , 'sl':sev_table })
```

Comment: Why don't you cache the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi I found an another method that to rendering to file.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
open(filename, "w").write(render_to_string(template, context))
```

and i am calling the filename(rendered page) in another app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cache_page decorator for the same.

```
@cache_page(60 * 15)
def severity_wise(request):
    sev_chart=[["Severity","No. of Bugs"]]
    ......
```

For further reading [click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#django.views.decorators.cache.cache_page)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want the page to be load faster every time.

Comment: Cache is used for the same reason. Try spending sometime to read more about the same. The way you're using to write on file is not a scalable approach. In future you might run parallel instances of your application which will cause redundant files.